# PHP subtract from MySQL query where "|" character

Tags: php, database, arrays

I have a array from the database which contains links, some values are normal as "index.php" but others look like "browse.php|search.php|calendar.php|tags.php?tags_mode=profile|search.php?show=match", but I only want to use the first path "browse.php" only and trash everything starting from the first "|" inclusively.. how can I do that?

This is the code I have:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE `Parent` = '0' AND Type LIKE 'top' ORDER BY `Order` ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: Query Failed! " .mysql_error());
    $output = "<ul>";
    while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

       $output .= "<li class='menu_top' id='".$rs['ID']."'><a href='".$rs['Link']."'>".$rs['Name']."</a></li>";
       $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE `Parent` = '".$rs['ID']."' ORDER BY `Order` ASC";
       $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die ("Error: Query Failed! " .mysql_error());
       if (mysql_num_rows($result2) != 0) {
          $output .= "<ul class='menu_sub' id='".$rs['ID']."'>";
          while ($rs2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
             $output .= "<li><a href='".$rs2['Link']."'>".$rs2['Name']."</a></li>";
          }
          $output .= "</ul>";
       }
    }
    $output .="</ul>";
    echo $output;
```

`$rs['Link']` is the one I want to be cut like that..

I tried to subtract but I can't really say I can manage it as I am too new to php..
Thank you for any advice..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only first element, you can use explode with limit:

```
$link=explode("|",$rs['Link'], 1);
echo $link [0];
```

Answer (score 1):

$link=explode("|",$rs['Link']);

```
$output .= "<li class='menu_top' id='".$rs['ID']."'><a href='".$link[0]."'>".$rs['Name']."</a></li>";
```

There you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure sql:

$sql = "SELECT *,IF(INSTR(`Link`,'|')>0,LEFT(`Link`,INSTR(`Link`,'|')-1),`Link`) AS `FormattedLink` FROM $tablename WHERE `Parent` = '0' AND Type LIKE 'top' ORDER BY `Order` ASC";